# Mysql import in table insert query

Tags: mysql

In file string (insert into ...) over 500k.
How to import in table data with only insert query?
Sample (over 500k lines)

```
INSERT INTO test(id, tag, group_id, photo_id, user_id, info) VALUES (555, 'city', 4444, 137187954, 67647144, 'ddddd');
INSERT INTO test(id, tag, group_id, photo_id, user_id, info) VALUES (444, 'city', 4444, 137187954, 67647144, 'fffff');
INSERT INTO test(id, tag, group_id, photo_id, user_id, info) VALUES (333, 'city', 4444, 137187954, 67647144, 'fffff');
```

Table:

```
create table test(
id int,
tag varchar(25),
user_id int,
photo_id int,
group_id int,
info varchar(256))
```

Load file in table:

```
mysql> load data local infile "E:/output00000.txt" into table test;
Query OK, 589975 rows affected, 65535 warnings (17.31 sec)
Records: 589975  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 3539850

mysql> select count(*) from test;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   589975 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.68 sec)

mysql> select * from test limit 500, 5;
+------+------+---------+----------+----------+------+
|  id  | tag  | user_id | photo_id | group_id | info |
+------+------+---------+----------+----------+------+
|    0 | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL | NULL |
|    0 | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL | NULL |
|    0 | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL | NULL |
|    0 | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL | NULL |
|    0 | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL | NULL |
+------+------+---------+----------+----------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**ANSWER**:

Change data to:

```
555 city    4444    137187954   67647144    ddddd
444 city    4444    137187954   67647144    fffff
333 city    4444    137187954   67647144    fffff
```

After execute:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "PATH" INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" (columns)
```

~20-30 min per million rows.

Comment: Is your table struture right? Your column `tag` is an `int` but you want to insert `city` - a `varchar`

Comment: Sorry, tag = varchar(25);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comma and give another list of values to insert:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (val1, val2, val3)
     , (val4, val5, val6)
     , (val7, val8, val9)
```

Comment: There's no difference at all. All result = NULL;